# Where does Grails and GGTS store maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, grails, grails-2.0

I'm having trouble refreshing dependencies with Grails 2.3.7 and eclispe GGTS 3.5.1

The `BuildConfig` for my main project is below; it depends on a single plugin, `acme`...

```
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

   inherits("global") 
   checksums true
   legacyResolve false 
   repositories {
      inherit false

   mavenRepo('http://...'){
      updatePolicy 'always'
   }
}

plugins {
   compile('acme:acme-core:0.10-SNAPSHOT)
}
```

Checked-in some changes for `acme`, then from GGTS do `refresh-dependencies`, and new snapshot files are downloaded; confirmed with `run-app`, binaries are consistent with changes; so far so good.

Check-in a few more changes for `acme`, and, even though Grails/GGTS recognizes the change and downloads new files, no matter what I do, the files are still the old ones.

**What I've confirmed so far:**

- Plugin files in source control are definitely updated
- Plugin version set to `0.10-SNAPSHOT`; main project referencing same version
- `refresh-dependencies` definitely downloading new pom/zip files

I tried the usual by deleting the following folders:

```
myProject
  /taret
  /target-eclispe

${userHome}
  .grails
    /2.3.7/
      /projects

${userHome}
  .m2
     /repository
       /acme
${userHome}
  .ivy
    (empty, not used anyway)
```

After deleting, perform `clean` + `refresh-dependencies` in GGTS, and new pom/zip files are downloaded, consistent with SNAPSHOT version/label, but binaries are still the old ones and do not reflect recent commits.

I tried the same using command line Grails (no GGTS), same crap.

Am I missing something? Is there a secret folder for plugins? Perhaps deleting my C:/ can cure this headache, ya know, to be safe? lol....Frankly, at this point, I don't know what else to do. I've had similar problems in the past, but a few `clean`s and `refresh`es takes care of it, but not this time.

Answer (score 4):

Grails uses the `grails.dependency.cache.dir` system property to determine where its dependency cache is.  By default, I believe that it is set to `grails.dependency.cache.dir = "${userHome}/.ivy2/cache"`.  You can override this by setting the property in your `~/.grails/settings.groovy` file or I believe you can also set it in your `BuildConfig.groovy`.  Even if you are using the Aether (Maven) dependency resolver, I believe that Grails will still copy the dependencies from your `.m2` to this cache.

Comment: As I previously mentioned, `${userHome}/.ivy` is empty on my system, but closer inspection revealed another ivy cache at `${userHome}/.grails/2.3.7/ivy-cache`, and it had a copy of plugin `acme`!, so let's see if this works...